# Some questions about model predictive control (MPC)

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, optimal-control

I have some questions about [model predictive control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_predictive_control) (MPC)

1. How does MPC use a system's model to forecast its future response?
2. How do model uncertainties and mismatches affect the performance of MPC, and what solutions have been proposed to address these issues?
3. What is offset-free tracking, and how is it achieved in MPC?
4. How does the addition of a disturbance model help in achieving offset-free tracking in MPC, and what are some methods for designing offset-free controllers?
5. What are the advantages of using state observers for estimating states and disturbances in  MPC, and how can observer gains be optimized for better performance?

Comment: You should be able to answer all of those questions by simply reading any standard textbook on MPC.